# What determines spring boots bean registration order for auto configurations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, activemq-artemis, spring-autoconfiguration

I have a multi-subproject Spring Boot 3.0 application built by gradle. In modules `A` and `B` I have beans with the annotations

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnBean(jakarta.jms.ConnectionFactory.class)
```

declared.

The actual `app` subproject containing the runnable boot application depends on both of these modules. Also module `B` depends on `A`. And `app` also has a `runtimeOnly` dependency on ActiveMQ Artemis to let Spring Boot's `ArtemisAutoConfiguration` do the configuration of the JMS connection factory via `ArtemisAutoConfiguration`.

However, when I look at the condition evaluation report after the application started I see that the condition did not match for the bean defined in subproject `A` but it did match for the bean defined in subproject `B`. Since `ConditionalOnBean` is evaluated during bean registration phase I suppose the bean definition for artemis is registered only after the bean in subproject `A` is registered but before the one in subproject `B`.

Can anyone explain what determines this order?

I already had a look at `BOOT-INF/classpath.idx` in the spring boot jar. But this shows `A` and `B` before any artemis and spring-boot-autoconfiguration entries. So I suppose it's not that.

NOTE: yes, using `@AutoConfigureAfter(ArtemisAutoConfiguration.class)` on the auto configuration of subproject `A` fixes this. I'm just curious to know why this was actually necessary to apply.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `@ConditionalOnBean`, but you also can control creation beans order with `@Order` and `@DependsOn`. I used `@DependsOn` and it works well. Here are two articles that may help:

1. [@Order in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-order),
2. [Controlling Bean Creation Order with
   @DependsOn Annotation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-depends-on)

Comment: This won't help because `ConditionalOnBean` is evaluated during bean registration and hence before bean creation. I also actually have an explicit `@DependsOn` because the mentioned bean methods with `@ConditionOnBean(ConnectionFactory.class)` also use the connection factory as a parameter. But if I start the application with jms disabled I only want these beans not to be created instead of the application failing to start because of the missing connection factory.

Comment: Than you can create different profiles and for a particular profile have some beans not registered. I think the profiles is your option